# How to create Revision URL using gcloud run?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, gcloud, google-cloud-run, revision

I recently noticed a beta feature in the Google Cloud Run web UI that allows you to create a Revision URL (tag). Super handy feature!

My question: how can I create a tag for a revision so I can do this using `gcloud`? I'm not seeing anything in the docs for it yet (probably because it's such a fresh feature).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The revision URL is also named "TAG". Use the update command to tag the latest revision.

```
gcloud beta run services update --tag=test --platform=managed --region=us-central1  go111
```

Comment: follow-up question: how do I now remove a tag from a revision? I'd like to delete revisions no longer in use, but once it's been tagged, I can only delete them by manually removing the tag using the UI. If I try to delete it directly on the UI or using `gcloud [beta] run revisions delete <revision>` I get the error `FAILED_PRECONDITION: Revision cannot be directly deleted because it is actively serving.` even though there's 0% traffic assigned to it.

Comment: Start by removing the tag ` gcloud beta run services update-traffic --remove-tags=test --platform=managed --region=us-central1 go111` and then you will be able to delete the revision!

Comment: I get `ERROR: (gcloud.beta.run.services.update) unrecognized arguments:
  --tag=def (did you mean '--args'?)`. Also, --tag doesn't show up in the help docs.

Comment: It's update-traffic, not update

Comment: Over a year later: now I want to delete those revisions, but I first need to clear the traffic tags from each revision. Not seeing in the docs how to get the traffic tags for a given revision. I see `--clear-tags`, but that clears all tags. Any pointers?

Comment: What do you want to do? List all revisions with tags?

Answer (score 5):

### Apr, 2022 Update:

You can add one or more tags for one or more revisions with **"gcloud"**. There are 2 ways to do it. One is **when creating a revision** and one is **for existed revisions**.

### <When creating a revision>

Now, there is **only one revision "editor-v1-0-0"** with **the tag "blue"** as shown below:

[image]

Then, to add **a tag** to a revision when creating it, this flag below is used:

```
--tag <tag>
```

Now, I'll add **the tag "green"** to a revision:

```
--tag green
```

Then, including the flag above, I run the full command referring to [**Shipping the public editor service**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/secure-services#shipping-frontend) in [**Securing Cloud Run services tutorial**](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/secure-services) as shown below to create a revision with **"editor:2.0.0" image**:

****When creating a revision, you can add only one tag to it.***

```
gcloud run deploy editor --image gcr.io/myproject-318173/editor:2.0.0 \
    --service-account editor-identity \
    --set-env-vars EDITOR_UPSTREAM_RENDER_URL=https://renderer-4bdlubpdxq-an.a.run.app \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --revision-suffix v2-0-0 \
    --no-traffic \
    --tag green // Here
```

Now, **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** with **the tag "green"** is created as shown below:

[image]

### <For existed revisions>

There are two commands **"gcloud run services update"** and **"gcloud run services update-traffic"** to add one or more tags. Actually, **"gcloud run services update-traffic"** can do more things about **Tag**:

#### <"gcloud run services update">

First of all, I'll show you how to add one or more tags with **"gcloud run services update"** and with **"gcloud run services update"**, you can add **only one tag at one command to only the latest revision**.

Now, there is **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"** with **no tags**:

[image]

Then, run the command with **the tag "green"** as shown below:

```
gcloud run services update editor --tag green
```

Now, **the tag "green"** is added to **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"** as shown below:

[image]

Then, if you run the command with **the tag "orange"** below:

```
gcloud run services update editor --tag orange
```

Now, **the tag "orange"** is added to **the latest revision "editor-v2-0-0"** without updating **"green"** to **"orange"** as shown below:

[image]

In addtion, if the tag which is already used for other revision is added to a revision, the tag is removed from other revision then added to a revision.

So, if running the command with **the tag "blue"** as shown below, **the tag "blue"** is removed from  **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"** then added to **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"**:

```
gcloud run services update editor --tag blue
```

[image]

#### <"gcloud run services update-traffic">

Next, I'll show you how to add one or more tags with **"gcloud run services update-traffic"**.

Now, there are **two revisions "editor-v2-0-0"** with **no tags** and **"editor-v1-0-0"** with **the tag "blue"**:

[image]

Then, this flag below **can add one or more tags to one or more revisions** but this flag below **cannot update one or more tags of one or more revisions** even though the flag name is **"--update-tags"** so this flag below **can just add one or more tags to one or more revisions**:

```
--update-tags <tag>=<revision>,…
```

Now, I'll add **the tag "green"** to **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"**:

```
--update-tags green=editor-v2-0-0
```

Then, including the flag above, I run the full command as shown below:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --update-tags green=editor-v2-0-0
```

Now, **the tag "green"** is added to **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** as shown below:

[image]

And, this command below can add **two tags "orange" and "yellow"** to **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** and **one tag "black"** to **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --update-tags \
orange=editor-v2-0-0,yellow=editor-v2-0-0,black=editor-v1-0-0
```

Now, **two tags "orange" and "yellow"** are added to **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** and **one tag "black"** is added to **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"** as shown below:

[image]

*Be careful, if there are **one or more empty strings before or after a comma in a list of values**, there is an error.

So, if an empty string is before a comma:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --update-tags \
orange=editor-v2-0-0 ,yellow=editor-v2-0-0,black=editor-v1-0-0
                 // An empty string before a comma
```

Then, there is an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update-traffic) unrecognized arguments: ,yellow=editor-v2-0-0,black=editor-v1-0-0

And if an empty string is after a comma:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --update-tags \
orange=editor-v2-0-0, yellow=editor-v2-0-0,black=editor-v1-0-0
　　　　　　　　　　 // An empty string after a comma
```

Then, there is an error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.run.services.update-traffic) unrecognized arguments: yellow=editor-v2-0-0,black=editor-v1-0-0

So, don't put **one or more empty strings before or after a comma in a list of values**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --update-tags \
orange=editor-v2-0-0,yellow=editor-v2-0-0,black=editor-v1-0-0
                 // No empty strings 
                 // before or after a comma
```

Next, this flag below **can update one or more tags of one or more revisions**:

```
--set-tags <tag>=<revision>,…
```

Now, there are **two revisions "editor-v2-0-0"** with **three tags "green", "orange" and "yellow"** and **"editor-v1-0-0"** with **two tags "blue" and "black"**:

[image]

Then, I'll update **three tags "green", "orange" and "yellow"** of **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** to **two tags "gold" and "silver"** and **two tags "blue" and "black"** of **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"** to **one tag "white"**:

```
--set-tags gold=editor-v2-0-0,silver=editor-v2-0-0,white=editor-v1-0-0
```

Then, including the flag above, I run the full command as shown below:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --set-tags \
gold=editor-v2-0-0,silver=editor-v2-0-0,white=editor-v1-0-0
```

Now, **three tags "green", "orange" and "yellow"** of **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** are updated to **two tags "gold" and "silver"** and **two tags "blue" and "black"** of **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"** are updated to **one tag "white"** as shown below:

[image]

Then, this flag below **can remove one or more tags from one or more revisions**:

```
--remove-tags <tag>,…
```

Now, there are **two revisions "editor-v2-0-0"** with **three tags "green", "orange" and "yellow"** and **"editor-v1-0-0"** with **two tags "blue" and "black"**:

[image]

Then, I'll remove **two tags "green" and "yellow"** from **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** and **one tag "blue"** from **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"**:

```
--remove-tags green,yellow,blue
```

Then, including the flag above, I run the full command as shown below:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --remove-tags green,yellow,blue
```

Now, **two tags "green" and "yellow"** are removed from **the revision "editor-v2-0-0"** and **one tag "blue"** is removed from **the revision "editor-v1-0-0"** as shown below:

[image]

Then, this flag below **can remove all tags** from **all revisions**:

```
--clear-tags
```

Now, there are **two revisions "editor-v2-0-0"** with **three tags "green", "orange" and "yellow"** and **"editor-v1-0-0"** with **two tags "blue" and "black"**:

[image]

Then, including the flag above, I run the full command as shown below to remove **all the tags** from **all the revisions**:

```
gcloud run services update-traffic editor --clear-tags
```

Now, **all the tags** are removed from **all the revisions** as shown below:

[image]